# How to select non "unique" rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table, from which i have to fetch non unique rows

| id | idA | infos |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 201 | 1899 |
| 1 | 205 | 1955 |
| 2 | 207 | 1955 |
| 3 | 201 | 1959 |

I'd like fetch all the rows for the column `infos`, that have a same `idA` value in at least two rows.

Output of the query for the above table must be

```
infos
1899
1959
```

I've tried the following requests with no success :

- `SELECT idA FROM XXX WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM XXX GROUP BY idA)`
- `SELECT * FROM XXX a WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM XXX b WHERE a.RVT_ID=b.RVT_ID GROUP BY idA)`

Comment: What database are you using, and what version of that database are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Select Every Row Where Column Value is NOT Distinct](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13146304/how-to-select-every-row-where-column-value-is-not-distinct)

Comment: It works in MySQL, so I'm adding that tag. I wonder if OP is around to change it to the correct SQL dialect/version?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT T1.idA, T1.infos
FROM XXX T1
JOIN
(
    SELECT idA
    FROM XXX
    GROUP BY idA
    HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
) T2
ON T1.idA = T2.idA
```

The result for the data you posted:

```
idaA  infos
201   1899
201   1959
```

Answer (score 37):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT idA, COUNT(*) FROM XXX GROUP BY idA HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 8):

```
SELECT id, idA, COUNT(infos) AS cnt
FROM mytable
GROUP BY infos
HAVING cnt > 1
```

Answer (score 2):

This is probably what you are looking for:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(DISTINCT infos) FROM table GROUP BY idA HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT infos) > 1;
```

Comment: It does not match "I'd like fetch all the rows for the column infos, that have a same idA value in at least two rows."

Answer (score 1):

This should give all the rows where "infos" appear exactly once (Tested on MySQL)

```
SELECT id, idA, count(infos) AS cnt
FROM mytable
GROUP BY infos
HAVING cnt=1
```

Data

```
id  ida     infos
1   201     1955
2   202     1978
3   203     1978
4   204     1956
5   0   1980
```

Result

```
id  idA     cnt
1   201     1
4   204     1
5   0   1
```

Comment: This will not work on all databases, it will on MySQL, but not on MSSQL Server (the latter won't allow non-aggregated columns that are not in the group by in the select)