# How to Select Every Row Where Column Value is NOT Distinct

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to run a select statement that returns all rows where the value of a column is not distinct (e.g. EmailAddress).

For example, if the table looks like below:

```
CustomerName     EmailAddress
Aaron            aaron@gmail.com
Christy          aaron@gmail.com
Jason            jason@gmail.com
Eric             eric@gmail.com
John             aaron@gmail.com
```

I need the query to return:

```
Aaron            aaron@gmail.com
Christy          aaron@gmail.com
John             aaron@gmail.com
```

I have read many posts and tried different queries to no avail.  The query that I believe should work is below.  Can someone suggest an alternative or tell me what may be wrong with my query?

```
select EmailAddress, CustomerName from Customers
group by EmailAddress, CustomerName
having COUNT(distinct(EmailAddress)) > 1
```

Answer (score 363, accepted):

This is significantly faster than the `EXISTS` way:

```
SELECT [EmailAddress], [CustomerName] FROM [Customers] WHERE [EmailAddress] IN
  (SELECT [EmailAddress] FROM [Customers] GROUP BY [EmailAddress] HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Comment: Hey, I know this answer is 7 years old, but if you're still around would you mind explaining how it works? Solved my problem as well!

Comment: Using a `HAVING` here instead of a second `SELECT...WHERE` causes this to be a single query, instead of the second option which executes that second `SELECT...WHERE` call many times. See more here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9253244/550975

Comment: I get the infamous `[EmailAddress] must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function` error. Is the only fix - editing the `sql_mode`?

Comment: Well, in the query above, `[EmailAddress]` IS in the `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 73):

The thing that is incorrect with your query is that you are grouping by email and name, that forms a group of each unique set of email and name combined together and hence

```
aaron and aaron@gmail.com
christy and aaron@gmail.com
john and aaron@gmail.com
```

are treated as 3 different groups rather all belonging to 1 single group.

Please use the query as given below :

```
select emailaddress,customername from customers where emailaddress in
(select emailaddress from customers group by emailaddress having count(*) > 1)
```

Comment: I like that you also included an explanation about what is wrong with the original query, unlike the accepted answer.

Answer (score 25):

```
select CustomerName,count(1) from Customers group by CustomerName having count(1) > 1
```

Comment: minor enhancment to show count as "dups": select CustomerName,count(1) as dups from Customers group by CustomerName having count(1) > 1`

Answer (score 13):

How about

```
SELECT EmailAddress, CustomerName FROM Customers a
WHERE Exists ( SELECT emailAddress FROM customers c WHERE a.customerName != c.customerName AND a.EmailAddress = c.EmailAddress)
```

Answer (score 11):

Just for fun, here's another way:

```
;with counts as (
    select CustomerName, EmailAddress,
      count(*) over (partition by EmailAddress) as num
    from Customers
)
select CustomerName, EmailAddress
from counts
where num > 1
```

Comment: +1 for CTE version
We shouldn't repeat ourselves in code, why repeat ourselves in SQL if we don't have to anymore.

Comment: I use _count for the count column (over num).  I consistently use underscore when columns happen to collide with SQL keywords like _default, _type, _sum, etc.

Comment: Loved it, much cleaner, and also the only one that was working accross multiple versions of MariaDB

Answer (score 4):

Rather than using sub queries in where condition which will increase the query time where records are huge.

I would suggest to use Inner Join as a better option to this problem.

Considering the same table this could give the result

```
SELECT EmailAddress, CustomerName FROM Customers as a 
Inner Join Customers as b on a.CustomerName <> b.CustomerName and a.EmailAddress = b.EmailAddress
```

For still better results I would suggest you to use `CustomerID` or any unique field of your table. Duplication of `CustomerName` is possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT        Title, Id
FROM            dbo.TblNews
WHERE        (Title IN
      (SELECT  Title 
FROM dbo.TblNews AS TblNews_1
GROUP BY Title
HAVING (COUNT(*) > 1)))
ORDER BY Title
```

- sort in title