# Select entries appearing in all results from another query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a single table.

This table has 2 fields, product IDs and Store IDs. The same product ID can exist with many different Store IDs.

I need to find the products (if any) that are common across all the stores.

I'm having difficulty constructing the correct query, any advice?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check distinct store ids count with product id. If distinct Store ids count equal to total stores that will be the product ids you want.

```
SELECT productID, count(DISTINCT StoreID) as stroes FROM [Table name] GROUP BY productID 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT StoreID) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT StoreID) FROM [Table name] );
```

Comment: That did the job. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you'll get many better answers, but it sounds like you are wanting the reverse of the distinct clause, not sure if this will work though:

SELECT NOT DISTINCT [Product_ID]
FROM TABLENAMEHERE

Comment: That won't work, just realised. How about something like this:

Comment: SELECT ProductIDFROM Customers WHERE EmailAddress IN
(SELECT EmailAddress FROM Customers GROUP BY EmailAddress HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)

Comment: Apologies, not used to enter being post!, follow this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13146304/how-to-select-every-row-where-column-value-is-not-distinct, which is where I got the full answer below from:  

SELECT ProductID
FROM Tablename WHERE ProductID IN
(SELECT ProductID FROM Tablename GROUP BY ProductID HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)

Comment: And the Order By ProductID at the end. Sorry, new to the forum, should have put that all in one query for you!

Answer (score 0):

You could sue count(distinct productID)

```
  select productID
  from my_table
  group by productID
  having count(distinct productID) = (    
                select count(distinct store)
                from my_table )
```