# Count distinct and non distinct values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an sql table looking like this:

```
+----+-----------+------------+
| Id | EnquiryId | PropertyId |
+----+-----------+------------+
|  1 |         1 |        20  |
|  2 |         1 |        25  |
|  3 |         1 |        26  |
|  4 |         2 |        20  |
|  5 |         3 |        20  |
|  6 |         4 |        20  |
+----+-----------+------------+
```

I want to count how many enquiries propertyid 20 has on it's own, and how many that is shared with other properties

So the result should be something like this:

Number of single enguiry: 3

Number of shared enquiries: 1

It's perfectly fine if it requires two select statements :)

The attempts so far looks like this:

```
(select count(distinct [EnquiryId]) 
from [EnquiryProperty] where propertyid=20) as 'SingleEnquiry'
```

This gave me 4 results (I need it to be 3)

```
(select count([PropertyId]) FROM [EnquiryProperty] where propertyid=20 GROUP BY propertyid HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) as 'MultipleEnquiry'
```

And this gave me 0 results

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your current attempts.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13146304/how-to-select-every-row-where-column-value-is-not-distinct @marcus-ohlsson

Comment: Ahem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521605/sql-server-query-selecting-count-with-distinct

Comment: which database?

Comment: My attemts so far looks like this: ,(select count(distinct [EnquiryId]) from [EnquiryProperty] where propertyid=325) as 'SingleEnquiry'
,(select count([PropertyId]) FROM [EnquiryProperty] where propertyid=325 GROUP BY propertyid HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) as 'MultipleEnquiry'

Comment: The database is SQL :)

Comment: @MarcusOhlsson:Is it sqlserver/oracle/mysql..also please share your expeceted result

Comment: A database cannot be SQL since SQL is the language in which you query the database.

Comment: @TheGameiswar: It's an sqlserver and the resultI need is 3 and 1

Comment: you can use `ctrl+k` to format code blocks

Comment: @DanteTheSmith You are right, I missunderstood the question from L30n1d45

Comment: @TheGameiswar: Thank you, I did'nt know that

Comment: @MarcusOhlsson:Glad you found it now..Stackoverflow is so helpfull,if you can follow a good format in asking questions.. you can check out this link to know more on how to ask a good question:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One method is two levels of aggregation.  The inner level assigns flags to each enquiry.  The second uses those to get the information you want:

```
select sum(is_20 * (1 - is_not_20)) as single_enquiry,
       sum(is_20 * is_not_20) as shared_enquiry
from (select enquiryid,
             max(case when propertyid = 20 then 1 else 0 end) as is_20,
             max(case when propertyid <> 20 then 1 else 0 end) as is_not_20
      from t
      group by enquiryid
     ) e;
```

Comment: Thank you verry much @SriniV, this works like a sharm :)

Comment: I like the idea with flagging 1st then aggregating the flags. Gonna keep that one in memory :)

Comment: @MarcusOhlsson, it was actually gordonlinoff to be thanked

Answer (score 1):

You can do same in 2 steps (its a tad easier to understand and has no nesting):

```
select count(PropertyId) AS Single20s
from WhateverTableIsCalled
group by EnguryId
having count(PropertyId) = 1

select count(PropertyId) AS Shared20s
from WhateverTableIsCalled
group by EnguryId
having count(PropertyId) > 1
```