# Update rows only when a join is unambiguous

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've got two tables, `a` and `b`, both with `product_name` and `value`. The value column in `a` is null.

I'd like to update the `a` table with values from the `b` table. Because of a quirk in the data, `product_name` is not unique in either table.

I only want to set the value when there is one unambiguous match on `product_name` between the two. When more than one row in `a` has the same product name, or more than one row matches from `b`, I'd like to keep the value empty. Is there an efficient way to do this in Postgres?

A simpler version of this would be to first [identify unique product names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13146304/how-to-select-every-row-where-column-value-is-not-distinct) in `a`. Then, update rows where only a single row in `b` matches -- but I'm also not sure how to write that constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way:

```
update a
set value = (select min(b.value) from b where b.product_name = a.product_name)
where product_name in (select product_name from a group by product_name having count(*) = 1)
  and product_name in (select product_name from b group by product_name having count(*) = 1)
;
```

Comment: (https://explain.depesz.com/s/SLZx) vs (https://explain.depesz.com/s/NBon)

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation:

```
update a
   set value = b.value
   from (select b.product_name, max(b.value) as value
         from b
         group by b.product_name
         having min(b.value) = max(b.value)  -- there is only one value
        ) b
   where b.product_name = a.product_name;
```

Note that this assumes that `b.value` is not `null`.  It is easy to include logic for `null` values, if that is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Just put together [[How to Select Every Row Where Column Value is NOT Distinct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13146304/how-to-select-every-row-where-column-value-is-not-distinct]) and @Gordon Linoff's answer:

```
create table a (
     id serial primary key
    ,product_name text 
    ,value int
);

create table b (
     id serial primary key
    ,product_name text 
    ,value int not null
);

insert into a (product_name) values
   ('A')
   ,('B')
   ,('C')
   ,('D')
   ,('E')
   ,('E');


insert into b (product_name,value) values
    ('A',1)
   ,('A',1) 
   ,('B',42)
   ,('C',1)
   ,('C',2)
   ,('E',1)
;

update a
   set value = b.value
   from (select product_name, min(value) as value
         from b
         group by b.product_name
         having 1 = count(*)
        ) b
   where b.product_name = a.product_name
     and a.product_name not in
     (select product_name
        from a
        group by product_name
        having 1 < count(*));
```

@Gordon Lindof your answer fails if product_name and value both dupilcated in b (example product_name=A) and misses the requirement product_name not duplicated in a.