# How to select all non unique columns from my DB?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014, having, information-schema

I'm learning SQL utilizing the common Microsoft `AdventureWorks2014` sample database in `SQL Server 2014`.

I just learned about `HAVING` and `Information Schema` today and am trying to combine the two.

Reason being, I'd really like to quickly tell which columns from all tables are shared. This works:

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME, TABLE_SCHEMA
```

But... the output gives me unique column names that only slows me down.

I've tried applying answers from ["How to select non 'unique' rows"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4519582/how-to-select-non-unique-rows) (among 5-7 other SOF pages!) such as:

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, COUNT(*)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
GROUP BY COLUMN_NAME
HAVING COUNT(COLUMN_NAME) > 1
```

...but I get this error:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Column
>   'information_schema.columns.TABLE_SCHEMA' is invalid in the select
>   list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or
>   the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your query, to retrive all the columns that are shared, and then join to the original table for all the information (schema, name):

```
SELECT t.TABLE_SCHEMA,
       t.table_name,
       t.column_name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS t
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT s.column_name
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS s
    GROUP BY s.column_name
    HAVING COUNT(s.column_name) > 1
) tt ON (t.column_name = tt.column_name)
```

Comment: Adding "ORDER BY column_name" at the end of your script did the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
        col = c.name,
        obj_name = o.name,
        sch_name = SCHEMA_NAME(o.[schema_id]),
        col_type = TYPE_NAME(c.system_type_id),
        RowNum = COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY c.name, o.[type] ORDER BY 1/0)
    FROM sys.columns c
    JOIN sys.objects o ON c.[object_id] = o.[object_id]
    WHERE o.[type] = 'U'
) t
WHERE t.RowNum > 1
ORDER BY t.col
```

Output:

```
col                     obj_name            sch_name  col_type    
----------------------- ------------------- --------- ------------
dbid                    spt_fallback_usg    dbo       smallint    
dbid                    spt_fallback_db     dbo       smallint       
xserver_name            spt_fallback_usg    dbo       varchar     
xserver_name            spt_fallback_db     dbo       varchar     
xserver_name            spt_fallback_dev    dbo       varchar
```